# Network packets capture bases process in Windows

Tags: windows, windows-8, packet-capture

I know some softwares can capture the network packets **bases process**, I only know WSexplorer, Commview. But they all work with some problem in my Windows8 system.

Is there any other application like them?

Answer (score 2):

If you are happy with the command line interface and wish to do a lot of other network packet investigation there is [scapy](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/) - it is a [python](http://python.org) based interface to the same libraries that are used by wireshark that does quite a lot more.

- Free
- Open Source
- Cross Platform
- Can create and dispatch packets in addition to capture and analysis including creating invalid/malformed packets if needed.

An example from the demo:

```
>>> res,unans = traceroute(["www.microsoft.com","www.cisco.com","www.yahoo.com","www.wanadoo.fr","www.pacsec.com"],dport=[80,443],maxttl=20,retry=-2)
Received 190 packets, got 190 answers, remaining 10 packets
   193.252.122.103:443 193.252.122.103:80 198.133.219.25:443 198.133.219.25:80  207.46...
1  192.168.8.1         192.168.8.1        192.168.8.1        192.168.8.1        192.16...
2  82.251.4.254        82.251.4.254       82.251.4.254       82.251.4.254       82.251...
3  213.228.4.254       213.228.4.254      213.228.4.254      213.228.4.254      213.22...
[...]
>>> res.graph()                          # piped to ImageMagick's display program. Image below.
>>> res.graph(type="ps",target="| lp")   # piped to postscript printer
>>> res.graph(target="> /tmp/graph.svg") # saved to file
```

[image]

3D Plot:

```
>>> res.trace3D()
```

[image]

Comment: thx alot what a beautiful and powerful application itis... but im under windows plantform and i think scapy couldnt support capture basing process or PID:)

Comment: AFAIK No network packets include a PID as it is meaningless off the platform and valid only for the duration of the process - instead they have a source and destination port but you can use psutil, https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil, net_connections, to get a list of open ports and the PIDs using them, then to get the name to match the PID.

Comment: sure that there IS NOT a PID infor within any packet because of none of level-3 business with levle-5. i think the only way combining PID and stream is basing system plantform program byself.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/download.html):

- free and open-source
- works on Windows/Linux/Mac
- can capture all network data:

[image]

Comment: but wireshark cannot capture bases process, i have to examine all the ports process using and set a expression in filter so that get almost(maybe not all) packets. disappointing...:(